# how to compress image size on client side Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to know how can i compress image size before sending it to spring java service in Angularjs,
I tried to use 'canvas' but image file loses input stream when sending it to backend .
any one can help.

Answer (score 0):

use [angular-image-compress](https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress). As described on github page, you can use it like:

```
<input id="inputImage" type="file" accept="image/*" image="image1" resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.7" resize-type="image/jpg" ng-image-compress />
```